# KafkaStreams: Sequential access vs time-bound in SessionStore

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

When you are Materializing a Store from a `SessionWindowKStream`, it forces you to do it as a SessionStore by setting
`Materialized<K,VR,SessionStore<org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Bytes,byte[]>> materialized)`.

So what you get is a `SessionStore<org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Bytes,byte[]>`. 
In this type of store, you can fetch by key, but not by key and time as in a `WindowStore`, even of the key type is a `Windowed<K>`. So you would have to iterate through it to find the time-related entries, which should be less efficient than querying by time.

How can you use the aggregated session store of `Windowed<K>` in order to query the store with (key, time)?

Or, put differently, why is there no `findSessions`-like methods (i.e. time-bound access) in `ReadOnlySessionStore`, while there is in `SessionStore`?

Comment: Missing feature. Feel free to create a ticket :)

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7622